# How to use Github Release API to make a release without source code?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am using blow command to publish a release on Github repo:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token xxxxxxxxx"  -d '{"tag_name": "test", "name":"release-0.0.1","body":"this is a test release"}'  https://api.github.com/repos/xxxxxx
```

I can see that a new release is created. But there are two download buttons under it:

```
Source code (zip)
Source code (tar.gz)
```

How can I make a release without source code?

If I can't remove the source code attachment, how can I upload additional binary files? I tried to use the API `Upload a release asset` like this: `POST https://<upload_url>/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id/assets?name=foo.zip`, it returns successfully but I couldn't find the binaries on Github release tab.

Comment: I'd love to have an answer to this too. I make source code releases for my libre software projects, uploading a source release tarball, and then I get bug reports saying "your build instructions don't work" because the user mistakenly but entirely reasonably  downloaded a file marked "Source code"!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a new release and upload additional binaries, you can :

- create the release using `POST /repos/:username/:repo/releases` and store the `upload_url` field from the response
- upload your asset using `POST $upload_url` with additional parameters `name` and optional `label` (refer to [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#input-2))

A quick example using `bash`, `curl` and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (JSON parser) :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

token=YOUR_TOKEN
repo=username/your-repo

upload_url=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token $token"  \
     -d '{"tag_name": "test", "name":"release-0.0.1","body":"this is a test release"}'  \
     "https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/releases" | jq -r '.upload_url')

upload_url="${upload_url%\{*}"

echo "uploading asset to release to url : $upload_url"

curl -s -H "Authorization: token $token"  \
        -H "Content-Type: application/zip" \
        --data-binary @test.zip  \
        "$upload_url?name=test.zip&label=some-binary.zip"
```

Comment: cool, it works. I wonder whether I can remove the source code zip download?

Comment: I don't think so, as releases are based on [git tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging), Github automatically show the SHA id it is bound to and provide source archive links for this tag. However, you can create/update a release at a specific commit / branch with `target_commitish` field (default is master branch)

Comment: what if I use the paid github account? will that be able to remove source code zip?

Comment: By `paid github account`, you mean using private repository? the release process is the same as public repo. As for Github Enterprise, I don't know

Comment: You ignored the "How can I make a release without source code?" part.

Answer (score 29):

You can control the contents of sourcecode archive within automatic generation using the [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file (and make it part of your repository).

Add lines like:

```
src export-ignore
```

to exclude the directory "src" from being part of the generated source package. Internally github uses "git archive" to create packages based on the tags - and "git archive" can be controlled via ".gitattributes".

Don't know whether you can avoid generating the source package completely - but this is at least a workaround to control the contents of the source code package

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it's cumbersome for large projects but the best suggestion at the moment. The current accepted answer is a beautiful overview of attaching assets to releases via the GitHub API, but does not answer the question of how to create releases without the source code bundles.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can on the community version. You can attach small binaries to the release though. I believe this is the way that GitHub works, as it is oriented around browsing the code, and providing the source is the important part.

Comment: If I can't remove the source code attachment, how can I upload additional binary files? I tried to use the API `Upload a release asset`, it returns successfully but I couldn't find the binaries on Github release tab.