# Gitlab Releases with specific files or folders instead of the whole repository

Tags: gitlab, release

Is there an option to pick specific files to be only included in a gitlab release instead of having to have the whole repository packaged as zip/tar files.

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── flow-definitions/                                       -- folder of flow definition
│   ├── main_flow_definition.json                           -- root flow definition for nifi instance
│   ├── bin/                                                -- folder for flow definitions impacted by dev cycle
│   │   ├── impacted_flow_definition.json
│   │   ├── impacted_flow_definition_2.json
│   │   └── ...
│   └── scripts/                                            -- scripts relevant to data pipelines
│       ├── databases/                                      -- DDL for target databases used in ETL
│       │   ├── db_name/
│       │   │   ├── <DDL scripts>
│       │   │   └── ...
│       │   └── ...
│       └── groovy/                                         -- Groovy scripts used in NiFi processors
│           ├── df_folder/
│           │   ├── <groovy scripts used in processors>
│           │   └── ...
│           └── ...
├── README.md
└── .gitignore
```

Currently I do the releases in gitlab through the UI and it packages the whole repository when a release is done. As you can see from the above folder structure majority of the time the changes are only within the `bin/` folder. As the docker file and other components don't usually change frequently.

So instead of packaging all the files, it would be good to release versions that just have the specific changed files in this case within the `bin/` folder.

I couldn't find a way to actually achieve this through gitlab if that's an option available

Comment: This probably helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408988/relase-single-file-for-download-on-gitlab/77326650#77326650